# Deciphering whether a set relying on a predicate exists

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm having some trouble with these style of questions in my Set Theory course and I'm not sure how to proceed with them.
[Screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLd0Q.png)

For part i) I tried something along the lines of "Let T denote the set in question. After a bit of manipulation, I arrived with T is an element of T if and only if T is an element of T. And, T is not an element of T if and only if T is not an element of T". No contradictions there but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about doing this style of question. Any suggestions?

for part ii), to me it seems like it's just denoting the set of all non empty sets which seems perfectly reasonable but I don't know if that's right. If it is, I wouldn't know how to write that more formally.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Clearly the predicates (i) and (iv) are negations of each other, as are the predicates (ii) and (iii), right?  So if (i) is a set, (iv) can't be, and vice versa, and similarly for (ii) and (iii).  (Do you see why?)  Can you use the fact that $x \not\in x$ for all $x$?  If so, then (i) is evidently the empty set, and (iv) is not a set.  And (iii) is the set containing only the empty set, so (ii) is not a set either.

Comment: (You're right that (ii) is the class of all non-empty sets, but that's a proper class, not a set.)

Comment: I didn't know x∉x was a fact, that clears things up a lot! I think the rest follows quite easily from that so I'll give this a go now. Thank you!